# Rearrange sloppy CSV file in python?

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I received some CSV data that is pretty sloppy. I would like to arrange it in python, but a few things are throwing me for a loop. Below are the header and sample first rows of the CSV file.

```
PATIENT,MD,REFMD,DIAGNOSIS_HISTORY,AVAILABLE_STUDIES
"last name, first name <odd character return>
name id <odd character return>
name age",doctor name <no quotes>
doctor name 2 <no quotes>,"referring doctor last name, first name ",studies <no quotes>,"history line 1
history line 2<odd character return>
history line 3"<odd character return>
```

This is what I would like to data to look like at the end result.

```
PATIENT,PATIENT ID, PATIENT AGE,MD1, MD2,REFMD,DIAGNOSIS_HISTORY,AVAILABLE_STUDIES
"name, name","name id","name age","doctor name","doctor name2","referring doctor last name, first name","studies","history line 1 history line history line 3"
```

I know I can do most of the rearranging with some for loops, but the character returns after the names, doctor name and history as well as the lack of quotes around the strings are confusing me.

Any suggestions as to how to clean up the data prior to transposing things around?

Comment: are you putting the <> values in to visualize the problem?

Comment: To me it looks as if one dataset consists of comma separated entries. Some of those are en-quoted some are not . The enquoted ones themselves each consist of several fields that are separated by some return-type-character. So first split into datasets/records (not sure what the separator is there, as you have only posted one record). Then split at commas, then strip quotes of fields (if there are any). then split by odd-return-character.

Comment: yes the <> is to point out the areas with issues.

Comment: so at <no quotes> and <odd character return>, are there actual (odd) characters or are they odd because they are there at all (or not, in case of the quotes)?

Comment: Here is how the data actually looks:    PATIENT,MD,REFMD,DIAGNOSIS_HISTORY,AVAILABLE_STUDIES
    >"last name, first name 
    >name id
    >name age",doctor name 
    >doctor name 2 ,"referring doctor last name, first name ",studies ,"history line 1
    >history line 2
    >history line 3"